# How can I translate Retail Marketing ?

Tags: traduction

I'm trying to translate my resume in Canadian French but I struggle finding a correct translation for "Retail Marketing Manager".

Is there a correct translation ?

Thanks

Comment: How about "Directeur du marketing de détail" ? (linguee.fr)

Answer (score 3):

Marketing translates to **commercialisation**.

In french Canada, job ads mostly use **Directeur/gérant de la commercialisation au détail**. More than often and from my experience, *marketing* is not translated and used as it is: **Directeur marketing**.

Source: french canadian, worked in retail

Answer (score 2):

My best guess would be : « Manager marketing et développement commercial »

It is officially listed and described in the rncp (National Directory of Professional Training) :
http://www.rncp.cncp.gouv.fr/grand-public/visualisationFiche?format=fr&fiche=27377

It's standard French though and might not be so good in Canadian French as they tend to avoid anglicisms.